# Telerik mvc grid and fixed width column

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

all my grids will have in the first column, some image links to edit, delete and open the record.

I can't get this column to be fixed at 80 pixels.

Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Handle))         
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        .Ajax()
        .Select("AjaxPesquisar", "Especialidade")
        .Update("AjaxAtualizar", "Especialidade")
        .Delete("AjaxDelete", "Especialidade"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid-padrao" })
    .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnDataBound("atualizarCss")
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(@<span><a class="formatacao" href="/Especialidade/Details/238" image="show"></a><a class="formatacao delete-link" href="/Especialidade/AjaxDelete/238" image="delete"></a><a class="formatacao" href="/Especialidade/Edit/238" image="edit"></a></span>).Width(80);
        columns.Bound("Descricao").Title("Descrição");
        columns.Bound("Handle").Title("Código");


    })        
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()

    )
```

Comment: Why was this down-voted? It is a valid and relatively straightforward question.

Answer (score 4):

Column widths work best if the `table-layout` CSS setting of the table is set to `fixed`. You can either make your grid Scrollable() or use the following CSS:

```
<style>
   .t-grid table
   {
      table-layout: fixed;
   }
</style>
```

You can find more info about tables [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html).

Comment: I used Scrollable and the body is now ok, but the headers is not the same size of body columns..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue too! What I did to get it work is to add:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.YourColumn)
.HtmlAttributes(new{@style="display:inline-block;width:80px;" });
```

Hope this helps.